# In ionic2, how to slideTo an index without animation?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have an array of images and I am showing 1st image in `Slide`, now I want to jump to nth position without showing the images between 1st and nth images. What is happening, the `slider` is sliding all the images between 1 and n very quickly, with animation. I want to skip all images in-between and directly show nth image.

Here's the code I am using to go to nth position.

```
this.slides.slideTo(this.SelecteduserIndex);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you can see in the **[Slide docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#slideTo)**, the `slideTo` method accepts the `speed` (transition duration in ms) as the second parameter:

```
> slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks)

Transition to the specified slide.

Param           Type      Details
index           number    The index number of the slide.
speed           number    Transition duration (in ms). (OPTIONAL)
runCallbacks    boolean   Whether or not to emit the ionSlideWillChange/ionSlideDidChange events. Default true. (OPTIONAL)
```

So you can use `0` as the speed to remove the animation, like this:

```
this.slides.slideTo(this.SelecteduserIndex, 0);
```

### **[Working Stackblitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-color-after-timeout-5trq5y)**